# Converting weeks of year to dates

Tags: r, date, type-conversion

I have a data set with number of weeks from the beginning of the year (`%W`), which I would like to convert to dates in order to plot it using date on x-axis

```
dat <- structure(data.frame(week = c(22, 34, 15), year = c(2009, 2009, 2010), x = c(3.4, 5.2, 1.3)))
```

I try to convert the weeks based on [earlier questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242955/converting-year-and-month-to-a-date-in-r) here, but end up getting `"YYYY-10-01"` for each date.

```
as.Date(paste("01", dat$week, dat$year, sep = "-"), format = "%d-%W-%Y")
```

Why is this and how can do it right?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
as.Date(paste("1", dat$week, dat$year, sep = "-"), format = "%w-%W-%Y")
```

A week and a year don't specify a date, so you do need a "day", but you need the "day of the week", or `%w`, rather than "day of the month", or `%d`. In this case, I used Monday (i.e. 1). Also, apparently `%w` doesn't like leading zeros.