# Sort year-month column by year AND month

Tags: r, date, sorting, yearmonth

I am trying to order a series of time data I have stored in a data frame. The format is of:

```
"%Y-%b"
```

Which looks like `"2009-Sep"`etc.

Until now I have managed to find this method:

```
ds[order(as.Date(ds$yearmonth, format = "%Y-%b")),]
```

But it only sort by year, and then it moves to alphabetical order regarding the months, giving me an order of `2009-Jan`, `2009-Jul`, `2009-Jun` etc. I am quite puzzled this is not an easy problem to fix.

Please help...

Best
Kasper

Comment: Have you looked at the output of `as.Date(ds$yearmonth, format="%Y-%b")`?

Comment: @mnel have you? That's not a valid Date. :-)

Comment: @GavinSimpson, I have. I was helping the OP clarify his question. :-).

Comment: My point is, if that is all the data he has, short of pasting on a day to each year-month, `as.Date` is the wrong tool here.

Comment: Yes, the question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242955/converting-year-and-month-to-a-date-in-r. My comment perhaps should have been slightly more clear, and less tongue-in-cheek (or oblique).

Comment: Thansk for the help guys. And sorry for not doing my homework completely, but the question sometimes asking the right question can be hard. I never thought of asking the question as the one in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242955/converting-year-and-month-to-a-date-in-r.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `as.yearmon()` function (and the `"yearmon"` class) in package **zoo** is designed for this sort of data:

```
dat <- c("2009-Sep","2009-Feb","2009-Jan")
require(zoo)
d2 <- as.yearmon(dat, "%Y-%b")
> sort(d2)
[1] "Jan 2009" "Feb 2009" "Sep 2009"
> order(d2)
[1] 3 2 1
> d2[order(d2)]
[1] "Jan 2009" "Feb 2009" "Sep 2009"
```

You could of course `paste0()` a day onto each date and coerce to class `"Date"` via `as.Date()` but `as.yearmon()` seems more natural to me:

```
> as.Date(paste0(dat, "-01"), "%Y-%b-%d")
[1] "2009-09-01" "2009-02-01" "2009-01-01"
```

Note you can generate that same result by coercing the `"yearmon"` object to class `"as.Date"`, e.g.:

```
> as.Date(d2)
[1] "2009-09-01" "2009-02-01" "2009-01-01"
```

Comment: One should remember that the vector class should be "character". Mine was by default "factor" giving my "NA" values.

Comment: @KasperChristensen Good point. That just goes to show the merits of reproducible examples. It is impossible to tell this from your question so I took you at your word that the data were character (that is what you show). `as.yearmon(as.character(dat), "%Y-%b"))` would be one way around the factor issue. Another would be to read your data in in the correct format in the beginning by specifying the variable classes, e.g. via `colClasses` in `read.table()` and its siblings..