# Missing months sorting df by Year and Month using as.yearmon() from zoo-package

Tags: r, date, locale, environment, zoo

I have problems sorting data by month and year. I'm using `as.yearmon()` as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15103562/how-to-sort-by-year-and-month-in-r-data-frame). However, some months are not recognized by `as.yearmon` function (march, mai, october, december). I found out that using German abbreviations instead of English abbreviations works fine, for example `Dez` instead od `Dec`. Also tried caps and no caps. It seems to by a default setting or I miss a command in the as.yearmon function. Ideas?? Here some sample data:

```
dat <- c("2009-Sep","2009-Feb","2009-Jan","2009-Oct")
require(zoo)
d2 <- as.yearmon(dat, "%Y-%b")
sort(d2)
```

In this case I lose the last entry 2009-Oct and I don't know why. My output is only:

```
"Jan 2009" "Feb 2009" "Sep 2009"
```

However, using this (note `Okt` instead of `Oct`, german style):

```
dat <- c("2009-Sep","2009-Feb","2009-Jan","2009-Okt")
```

I get the wright output. Do you have ideas how to solve this problem? Thanks

Comment: Not able to reproduce the problem.  `sort(as.yearmon(dat, "%Y-%b"))
#[1] "Jan 2009" "Feb 2009" "Sep 2009" "Oct 2009"`

Comment: what do you mean by "lose". can you add the output that you get.

Comment: I only get `"Jan 2009" "Feb 2009" "Sep 2009"` see my edit

Comment: In that case, you might need to check the settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You possibly need to change the `locale` [settings](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/zoo/vignettes/zoo-quickref.pdf):

```
 Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "C")
```

If that does not work you can [start R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16347731/how-to-change-the-locale-of-r-in-rstudio) with `"LANG="C"`