# time series plot in R

Tags: r, time-series

My data looks something like this:

There are 10,000 rows, each representing a city and all months since 1998-01 to 2013-9:

```
RegionName| State|  Metro|         CountyName|  1998-01|      1998-02|  1998-03

New York|   NY| New York|   Queens|         1.3414|   1.344|             1.3514

Los Angeles|    CA| Los Angeles|    Los Angeles|    12.8841|     12.5466|   12.2737

Philadelphia|   PA| Philadelphia|   Philadelphia|   1.626|    0.5639|   0.2414

Phoenix|            AZ| Phoenix|            Maricopa|    2.7046|       2.5525|  2.3472
```

I want to be able to do a plot for all months since 1998 for any city or more than one city.

I tried this but i get an error.  I am not sure if i am even attempting this right.  Any help will be appreciated.  Thank you.

```
forecl <- ts(forecl, start=c(1998, 1), end=c(2013, 9), frequency=12)

plot(forecl)

Error in plots(x = x, y = y, plot.type = plot.type, xy.labels = xy.labels,  : 
  cannot plot more than 10 series as "multiple"
```

Comment: Why start in 1998 if the data starts in 2005? You should post `dput(head(forecl))`. You should also specify what design for the plot. All years and months in sequence ,or all Jan-Dec stacked? Probably will work better if you reshape to long format.

Answer (score 1):

You might try

```
require(reshape)
require(ggplot2)
forecl <- melt(forecl, id.vars = c("region","state","city"), variable_name = "month")
forecl$month <- as.Date(forecl$month)
ggplot(forecl, aes(x = month, y = value, color = city)) + geom_line()
```

Comment: thank you for your response.  I tried forecl$month <- as.Date(forecl$month); forecl$month <- as.Date(forecl$month, "%d.%b.%Y"); forecl$month <- as.Date(forecl$month[,1], "%d.%b.%Y") and I get the same error:  
Error in as.Date.default(forecl$month[, 1], "%d.%b.%Y") : 
  do not know how to convert 'forecl$month[, 1]' to class “Date”; I am trying to research what is wrong with my code...

Comment: Ah, sorry, didn't notice your date was in %Y-%m format.  Try following [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242955/converting-year-and-month-to-a-date-in-r) and use forecl$month <- as.Date(paste(forecl$month,"-01",sep=""), "%Y-%m-%d"), or using the zoo package.

Answer (score 1):

To add to @JLLagrange's answer, you might want to pass `city` through `facet_grid()` if there are too many cities and the colors will be hard to distinguish.

```
ggplot(forecl, aes(x = month, y = value, color = city, group = city)) +
  geom_line() +
  facet_grid( ~ city)
```

Comment: Good suggestion -- with 10000 rows, it might even make sense to get a 2-D grid, like facet_grid(state ~ metro),

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide an example of your data, e.g. `dput(head(forecl))`, **before** converting to a time-series object? The problem might also be with the `ts` object.

In any case, I think there are two problems.

First, data are in wide format. I'm not sure about your column names, since they should start with a letter, but in any case, the general idea would be do to something like this:

```
test <- structure(list(
  city = structure(1:2, .Label = c("New York", "Philly"), 
  class = "factor"), state = structure(1:2, .Label = c("NY", 
  "PA"), class = "factor"), a2005.1 = c(1, 1), a2005.2 = c(2, 5
  )), .Names = c("city", "state", "a2005.1", "a2005.2"), row.names = c(NA, 
  -2L), class = "data.frame")

test.long <- reshape(test, varying=c(3:4), direction="long")
```

Second, I think you are trying to plot too many cities at the same time. Try:

```
plot(forecl[, 1])
```

or

```
plot(forecl[, 1:5])
```

Comment: I edited my post to include real col names and few rows; R reads all col names starting with a character; thank you for your help