# as.date coercion in R

Tags: r, as.date

*Hello, I cannot figure out where the problem is even after consulting the documentation for as.Date, although it must be a very silly thing.
I have a character vector DD that contains dates:*

```
 unique(DD)
      [1] NA        "1999-01" "2013-08" "2013-02" "2013-03" "2013-01" "2013-07" "2012-12" "2013-05"
     [10] "2012-11" "2013-04" "2013-06" "2011-11" "2011-12" "2011-06" "2010-07" "2011-01" "2010-03"
```

*I want to convert it into date format. I tried*

```
DD2 = as.Date(DD, format = "%Y-%m")
```

*but the result gives only NAs :*

```
 unique(DD2)
[1] NA
```

*Can anyone see the problem?*

Comment: I'm pretty sure the `Date` class requires year, month, and day elements. You could just make each element the first of the month like this: `as.Date(paste0(na.omit(DD),"-01"))`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242955/converting-year-and-month-to-a-date-in-r

Comment: @GSee Drat, that's a better duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure why this doesn't work, but it appears you do have to completely specify the date for `as.Date` to work.  Instead, you could use `as.yearmon` from the `zoo` package.