# Strange NAs in R when converting characters in "%Y/%m" format to dates with as.POSIXct

Tags: r, datetime

I am trying to use `as.POSIXct` in `R` to convert a vector of characters with the following format: "YYYY/MM"

Unfortunately, I have discovered a strange error -- the following code returns `NA`:

```
as.POSIXct("2014/12", "%Y/%m")
[1] NA
```

When I interpret the second number as a day everything works fine:

```
as.POSIXct("2014/12", "%Y/%d")
[1] "2014-07-12 CDT"
```

If I add a third number representing a day of month, everything works fine:

```
as.POSIXct("2014/12/01", "%Y/%m/%d")
[1] "2014-12-01 CDT"
```

Anybody have any idea why I'm getting an `NA` for the first code chunk?

Comment: posix needs to know a day, you haven't given it one - you cant given it a month only - what day of the month do you want to represent? See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6242980/3760920)

Comment: The first day of the month is probably fine.  So I would just need to add "/01" to the end of each character string?

Comment: Sure, try as.POSIXct(paste(DATE,"/01",sep=""), "%Y/%m/%d")

Comment: Cool, thanks.  I didn't realize that as.POSIXct always expected a day.

Comment: It has nothing to do with `as.POSIXct` in particular. This won't work with `as.Date` neither. R simply doesn't have a `yyyy/mm` only class. You can use the `zoo` package if you want to use one- as per the dupe link.