# Convert character field to quarter date in R

Tags: r

i have a tsv where there is a date field (named "trim")in quarter format

```
 trim
 1992-4
 1993-1
 ...
```

When i load the file as data frame, R imports that field as character.

i can't convert it, i get NA only, even if I try:

```
 df$trim <- as.Date(df$trim, format="%Y-%q")
```

or loading the zoo package and send this command:

```
as.yearqtr(df$trim, format="%Y-%q")
```

Any idea?

Comment: `%q` is not a format listed in `?strptime`.  I don't think you can store the year-quarter date object.  However, storing it as a factor should be just fine, as the way in which this is generated will still sort as desired.

Comment: @Benjamin With `zoo` package, you can store year-quarter object as `yearqtr`. But it in the format `YYYY Qx`.

Comment: I stand corrected.  Although, based on the documentation of `?zoo::yearqtr`, there doesn't appear to be a straightforward way to convert these character strings to `yearqtr` objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you *insist* on using the base R `as.Date()` function, then one option for you to consider is mapping the quarters to months.  In the below code, I map the quarter to the first month occurring in that quarter.  Then I tag on `"01"` for the first day in that month, and afterward convert to a date.

```
trim <- c("1992-4", "1993-1")

trim <- gsub("-1", "-01", trim)       # map first quarter to January
trim <- gsub("-2", "-04", trim)       # map second quarter to April
trim <- gsub("-3", "-07", trim)       # map third quarter to July
trim <- gsub("-4", "-10", trim)       # map fourth quarter October

trim <- paste(trim, "-01", sep="")    # add first day of the month

trim <- as.Date(trim, "%Y-%m-%d")     # convert to date

> trim
[1] "1992-10-01" "1993-01-01"
```

P.S. This question is sort of a duplicate of [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242955/converting-year-and-month-to-a-date-in-r).  But it's different enough to merit a new answer IMO.

Comment: thank you,  so i can't use the quarter format date to plot something. With ggplot2 i must work on scales and labels

Comment: Check out the comment from @Pascal ... baseR doesn't have a quarter date object although other packages (e.g. `zoo`) might have this.

Answer (score 5):

This converts a character string to `"yearqtr"` class and `"Date"` class (first of quarter) and `"Date"` class (last of quarter):

```
library(zoo)

as.yearqtr("1992-4")
## [1] "1992 Q4"

as.Date(as.yearqtr("1992-4"))
## [1] "1992-10-01"

as.Date(as.yearqtr("1992-4"), frac = 1)
## [1] "1992-12-31"
```

Note that zoo has `scale_x_yearqtr` for defining a ggplot2 X axis suitable for `"yearqtr"` class.

Answer (score 3):

You can use lubridate.
It can be loaded using tidyverse.

```
library(tidyverse)
yq('1992-4')
str(yq('1992-4'))

parse_date_time('1992-4',orders = "Yq")
parse_date_time('1992-4',orders = "%Y%q")

[1] "1992-10-01"
Date[1:1], format: "1992-10-01"
[1] "1992-10-01 UTC"
[1] "1992-10-01 UTC"
```