# Convert date in YYYY-MM-DD format to YYYY-MM

Tags: r, date

I would like do perform the reverse of [R converting a factor YYYY-MM to a date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33058938/r-converting-a-factor-yyyy-mm-to-a-date).

I have a data frame (df) with dates presented as YYYY-MM-DD format (column "Date1") and would like to convert them into YYYY-MM format. The days range between 0-31 but these aren't necessary for my YYYY-MM format.

The point is that I have another set of columns that are in YYYY-MM format (column "Date2") and want to calculate the differences between them in whole months (values x, y and z in column "Difference(months)")

```
Date1       Date2    Difference(months)
2008-08-11  1995-02    x
2010-06-18  1972-09    y
2011-04-22  1956-11    z
```

Doing `df$Date1_new <- as.Date(df$Date1, "%Y-%m")` just gives a series of "NA" values.

Please can you give me a way that does what I am asking for or another easier method that gives the same desired result?

Comment: You have to first convert them to proper `Date`s and then use `format`

Comment: Please explain what you mean by converting to proper dates and using format. Convert what?

Comment: I mean something like `format(as.Date(df$Date1, "%Y-%m-%d"), "%Y-%m")`

Comment: Please can you mark this as an answer. Thank you for your help

Comment: Another option is using the `as.yearmon` function from the `zoo` library.

Comment: @Bob, feel free to put my comment in an answer of your own and mark it as accepted. I believe it's a duplicate question but can't find a good dupe at the moment

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `format(as.Date(df$Date1, "%Y-%m-%d"), "%Y-%m")` works for converting 2008-08-11 to 2008-08 - as suggested by @docendo discimus