# R: sorting a data frame by two columns "Year" and "Month"

Tags: r, datetime

I have a data frame `DF` which has a column `Month` as a character string using the full English name of the month, and a column `Year` as numeric:

```
Year Month {several xi}        
2016 April {numeric}
```

I need to plot several of the xi as a time series. What is the most efficient way to sort this data frame from the earliest month (January 2015) to the present? My attempts to convert "month" into a date-classed object using `as.Date` are not working as I'd like; they keep coming back sorted alphabetically.

Apologies if this is a noob question, but by sheer bad luck I have not had to work with date-class objects very often in my R career, so I'm not sure which of the various similar questions I am seeing can help me.

Comment: `month.name` is a built-in constant with the months in the correct order. Simply do `df$Month = factor(df$Month, levels = month.name)` to create a factor with the proper ordering. You can then `df[order(df$Year, df$Month), ]`.

Comment: You won't be able to make it a `Date` without a day - you could use `1` for the day. You could use the `yearmon` class of the `zoo` package, almost exactly [as in this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6242955/903061), but you'll need to use `%B` instead of `%m` since you have unabbreviated month names. See `?strptime` for other datepart wildcards.

Answer (score 0):

I concur with Gregor's suggestion of using the `zoo` package.  I think it is good practice to combine dates into one variable.  If you ever need to extract information about only the year or month you can use the `lubridate` package.  Here is a simple example of how to use `zoo`.

```
library(zoo)

#Toy Data Set
d <- data.frame( Month = c("March", "April", "May", "March"), Year = c("2008", "1998", "1997", "1999"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

#Generating Yearmon
d$my <- as.yearmon(paste(d$Month, d$Year)) 

#Ordering the data
d <- d[order(d$my), ]
```

Make sure that the month and year variables in your data frame are not factors.  They must respectively be of a character and numeric/integer class.

One note, if you plan to use `ggplot` instead of `plot` then you'll need to use `scale_x_yearmon()`.

Finally, you mention that you had trouble with `as.Date`.  As Gregor notes, this is because `as.Date` expects a format which contains a day, month and year.  Therefore in your case you can insert an arbitrary day to use `as.Date`.  For example, `as.Date(paste(d$Month, 1, d$Year), "%B %d %Y")`.  For a complete list of the different date formats read [this](http://www.statmethods.net/input/dates.html).

Comment: Thanks to all responders. Both ordering by `month.name` and using `as.Date(paste(d$Month, 1, d$Year), "%B %d %Y")` worked like a charm. The file is quite big and I'm importing a fair number of packages already, so I avoided using `zoo`, but I'll keep it in mind.