# Aggregate data in an xts object by time and second (factor) variable

Tags: r, aggregate, xts

I'm new to time series analysis and using xts (and R in general) so please forgive the basic nature of the question.

I'm wanting to aggregate the data by a time frame (e.g. months) and by a second factor variable. To illustrate my question, please see the following:

```
require(xts)

# Create example df and convert it to an xts object 

date <- sample(seq(as.Date("2015/01/01"), as.Date("2016/12/31"), by="day"),12)
colour <- c("Red", "Red", "Blue", "Blue", "Blue", "Blue", "Red", "Red", "Red", 
            "Red", "Blue", "Blue")
value <- sample(1:10, 12, replace = TRUE)
df <- cbind.data.frame(date, colour, value)
df <- xts(df[,-1], order.by = df$date)
```

This creates a sample dataframe that looks like this:

```
         colour value
2015-01-30 "Blue" "2"  
2015-03-15 "Blue" "9"  
2015-03-22 "Blue" "9"  
2015-08-13 "Blue" "5"  
2015-09-01 "Blue" "8"  
2015-11-10 "Red"  "7"  
2016-04-26 "Blue" "2"  
2016-07-06 "Red"  "9"  
2016-07-07 "Red"  "6"  
2016-07-08 "Red"  "2"  
2016-10-01 "Red"  "6"  
2016-11-07 "Red"  "2"
```

I can summarise the "value" variable using:

```
apply.monthly(df$value, FUN = mean)
```

To give me:

```
             value
2015-01-30 2.000000
2015-03-22 9.000000
2015-08-13 5.000000
2015-09-01 8.000000
2015-11-10 7.000000
2016-04-26 2.000000
2016-07-08 5.666667
2016-10-01 6.000000
2016-11-07 2.000000
```

But I can't quite see how to aggregate by (in this case) the colour variable (I'd like the sum of each colour by month). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
aggregate(as.numeric(df$value),
          list(Month = format(index(df), "%Y-%m"), 
               Colour = df$colour), 
          mean)
```

In response to your comment below:

```
# You can replace the format with the following to get a year month object
zoo::as.yearmon(index(df))

# Or you can covert to date by using the first of every month
as.Date(paste(format(index(df), "%Y-%m"), "-01", sep = ""))
```

You might find more ideas here: [Converting year and month ("yyyy-mm" format) to a date in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242955/converting-year-and-month-yyyy-mm-format-to-a-date-in-r)

Comment: Very helpful @NBATrends This solution works but creates a "Month" variable that is class "Character". Is there a way to ensure that the output remains as class "Date"? I did try `as.Date(df$Month, format = "%Y-%m")` but to no avail. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to work with xts objects after subsetting by colour, it's easy to work with each time series (by colour) separately in a list like this:

```
df <- cbind.data.frame(date, colour, value)

> class(df)
#[1] "data.frame"

# data.frame split (not xts split) to separate data by colour in a list object:
l_out <- split(df, colour)

> class(l_out[[1]])
[1] "data.frame"

mthly_mean <- function(x) {
    apply.monthly(as.xts(x[, "value"], x[, "date"]), mean)    
}

# Each element in the list is an xts object (not a data.frame) containing the mean of the data for each month:
l_res <- lapply(l_out, FUN = mthly_mean)
# or more succinctly:
# l_res <- lapply(l_out, FUN = function(x) apply.monthly(as.xts(x[, "value"], x[, "date"]), mean))

> l_res
# $Blue
# [,1]
# 2015-01-15  8.0
# 2015-07-21  4.5
# 2016-01-28  5.0
# 2016-04-28  4.0
# 2016-05-08  2.0
# 
# $Red
# [,1]
# 2015-11-30    3
# 2016-01-18    7
# 2016-02-25    5
# 2016-04-17    1
# 2016-05-23    6
# 2016-07-14    5

> class(l_res[[1]])
[1] "xts" "zoo"
```