# R data processing and forecasting

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

I am a new R user. I have data in the following xls file

```
nKPI    December-2012   July-2013   January-2014    July-2014   January-2015    June-2015   January-2016    July-2016

NKPI-03001 0.13 0.25    0.23    0.09    0.07    0.08    0.19    0.14
NKPI-03002 0.23 0.22    0.21    0.16    0.20    0.22    0.32    0.37
NKPI-03003 0.38 0.41    0.44    0.36    0.32    0.28    0.36    0.35
NKPI-03004 0.47 0.37    0.49    0.38    0.41    0.43    0.51    0.54
NKPI-03005 0.24 0.41    0.55    0.43    0.41    0.42    0.54    0.52
NKPI-03006 0.31 0.38    0.39    0.36    0.34    0.40    0.59    0.55
NKPI-03008 0.20 0.21    0.17    0.09    0.10    0.13    0.25    0.29
```

There are 704 rows of nkpi entries to process.

I need to forecast a value for july 2017 and jan 2018 using this data and create a plot for each kpi.

I can read the data into a data frame and drop rows with missing data as follows:

```
kpi_df <- read.xls("ochre_kpi.xls", header=TRUE)
# drop rows with no or missing data
kpi_df <- na.omit(kpi_df)
```

At this stage I get lost. I thank in advance any one who can offer guidance and assistance

Answer (score 1):

It's best to work in tidy data format in R (if you're not sure what this is, get googling). I'm a big fan of tidy tools in the `tidyverse` library. If you're curious as to why I think it's preferred, you could read Hadley Wickham's tidy tools manifesto. You can find tutorials online, specifically DataCamp, and look to the RStudio cheatsheets for help (RStudio -> Help -> Cheatsheets). In terms of getting started on the analysis above, this should do.

Note: when loading a package (this is done with the call `library(name_of_package)`) for the first time, you'll need to call `install.packages('name_of_package')` to install the package.

Start with data cleaning.
To get data into tidy format:

```
library(tidyverse)
kpi <- dplyr::gather(kpi_df, key="date", value="value")
```

This would make your table `kpi` look like:

```
nKPI             date                   value
NKPI-03001       December-2012          0.13
NKPI-03001       July-2013              0.25
```

The next thing to do would be to look get R to understand that the `date` column has dates in it. I'd normally recommend `lubridate::parse_date_time` which is on page 37 of this [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lubridate/lubridate.pdf). However, since your dates only have year and month, you run in to the same problem as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242955/converting-year-and-month-yyyy-mm-format-to-a-date-in-r). To get around that, the `zoo` package is good, so no lubridate this time. The code to fix your dates would be:

```
library(zoo)
kpi <- kpi %>% mutate(date = zoo::as.Date(zoo::as.yearmon(date, "%B-%Y"))
```

Now your data is cleaned and ready to go!

To plot: I'd use `ggplot()` because of the facet abilities, since you want a plot for each kpi.

```
# Plot value over time
ggplot(data=kpi, aes(x=date, y=value) +
    # Type of plot is scatter plot
    geom_point() +
    # Separate plots by the nKPI variable
    facet_grid(~nKPI)
```

As for making a prediction, the function to generate a linear regression model is `lm()`. You can read about it by typing `?lm` into your R console.

Hope this all helps! Welcome to R!

Comment: Thank you for great start. Seems to be missing ) in ggplot command. I need to plot each kpi on its own, so how do I loop over each one, producing 1 plot per kpi?

Comment: @ozhank that's what `facet_grid` does.