# How to extract month from a Year-Month (2017-10) type object in R?

Tags: r, date, format

This object is in character format and i would like to avoid extracting the 10 by string based functions since it is very cumbersome. If there is a way through as.Date() and some particular format, i would be happy to use that

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242955/converting-year-and-month-yyyy-mm-format-to-a-date

Comment: Because 6,7 is not generic. Month could be 5 as well as 12

Comment: The least cumbersome would probably just be a regex that captures all digits from "-" to the end.

Comment: library(stringr); str_extract("2010-10", pattern = "[0-1]?[0-9]$")

Answer (score 1):

I've really been enjoying `anydate` from the `anytime` package lately.

Try this:

```
library(anytime)
format(anydate("2017-10"), "%m")
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this question has been asked before on SO.

As an alternative to the `anytime` package you may use `lubridate`

```
library(lubridate)
format(ymd("2017-10", truncated = 1L), "%m")
```

or with base R

```
format(as.Date(paste0("2017-10", "-01")), "%m")
```

Answer (score 0):

This converts it to a yearmon object (which represents a year and month with no day) and then extracts the month.  See `?yearmon` for more information.

```
library(zoo)

cycle(as.yearmon("2017-10"))
## [1] 10
```