# is as.POSIXct mandatory to specify a date column?

Tags: r, posixct

I have a date frame with dates.

```
customer <-c("57","49687","4564","654654")
date     <- c("11-2016","01-2017","02-2017","12-2016")
df       <- data.frame(customer,date)
```

However, if  I want to use as.POSIXct() to change the format, it exhibits a column of NAs but does not show any warning messages.

```
df$date <- as.POSIXct(as.character(df$date),format = "%m %Y")
```

How can I use properly as.POSIXct() in this setting?

Comment: Your dates are missing the days. So `as.POSIXct` is not able to convert them (and btw the format should have been `"%m-%Y"`).

Comment: POSIXct has a date+time structure. For just the date, you can use `as.Date`

Comment: This might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242955/converting-year-and-month-yyyy-mm-format-to-a-date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @nicola stated you are missing the day.  If you want to assume the day as the first of the month, you can paste in the day as the first using:

```
df$date <- as.POSIXct(paste(df$date, "01", sep="-"), format="%m-%Y-%d")
```