# Calculate age using two datums of different formats

Tags: r

I am having a problem to calculate the age of all my participants.

I have the date of birth recorded only in terms of month and year (XX/XXXX) and I have the exact date when the data was recorded (XX/XX/XXXX).

I wanted to use the age_calc function from the eeptools package to calculate the age.
Unfortunately, something does not work. I suspect it is because one date is exact whereas the other is not specifying the exact date.

This is what I have tried:

```
df$birthdate <- as.Date(df$birthdate)
df$visitdate <- as.Date(df$visitdate)
age <- age_calc(df$birthdate,enddate=df$visitdate, unit="year")
```

The response I get is:
"Both dob and enddate must be Date class objects".

So what I am thinking is to change the birthdate to always the first day of the month in order to get it to work. Unfortunately, I don't know how to do that. Can anyone help out? Is there a better way of handling this problem?

Thanks in advance!
Lukas

Comment: You need to specify the `format` argument in `as.Date(df$birthdate)` as `"%m/%Y"` You must have seen this error: "character string is not in a standard unambiguous format"

Comment: Related / dupe: [Converting year and month (“yyyy-mm” format) to a date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242955/converting-year-and-month-yyyy-mm-format-to-a-date)

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply Markus! I have tried specifying the format. Unfortunately, this resulted in all data points being transformed to NA without any error message. Do you know why this could have happened?

Comment: Show us an example of your data, probably it's a format problem.

Comment: It worked for the visit date which is specified as follows: "2019-01-25". It did not work for the birthdate which is specified as "1950-07".
Here is the command I have used:
    df$brthdat <- as.Date(df$brthdat,"%Y-%m")

Comment: Since you're passing `units="year"`, use `as.Date(paste0(df$brthdat, "-01"))`, in order to get the birthdate to the same format. `paste0("1950-07", "-01")` adds the day.

Comment: It worked, you're awesome! Last question. How can I get the age to be precise. If someone is 75.8 years old I would like the number to be 75. I have tried to use precise=TRUE without any effect. Thanks so much!

Comment: Use `floor()` on the output from `age_calc()` or `precise = FALSE`.

Comment: It worked, thanks! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `paste0()` in order to add the day to the date:

```
as.Date(paste0(df$brthdat, "-01"))
```

So:

```
df$brthdat <- as.Date(paste0(df$brthdat, "-01"))
df$visitdate <- as.Date(df$visitdate)

library(eeptools)
age <- age_calc(df$birthdate,enddate=df$visitdate, unit="year", precise = FALSE)
```