# I have a simple question. convert yyyy-mm to yyyy-mm-dd in r

Tags: r

I have a column called months in the format yyyy-mm e.g "2010-01" "2010-02" "2010-03". It is in chr but i want to change it to Date format i.e yyyy-mm-dd. How do I add the "dd" to be the first day of every month e.g "2010-01-01" "2010-02-01" "2010-03-01" and convert the column from chr to date format

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting year and month ("yyyy-mm" format) to a date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242955/converting-year-and-month-yyyy-mm-format-to-a-date)

Comment: Yes it does. Thank you