# How to convert a entire column in R character to Date if I use Tibble

Tags: r, tibble, as.date

I am very new in R. So, I have some difficulties. 
I have a database in tibble (R language), where my first column is in character so i want to convert to date but I can't. I tried this code:

```
as.Date(x$Date, "%m-%y")
```

But doesn't work.

This is an example that follows

```
 <chr>
01-02
02-02
03-02
04-02
05-02
06-02
07-02
08-02
```

Do y'all have some tips to solve this little problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting year and month ("yyyy-mm" format) to a date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242955/converting-year-and-month-yyyy-mm-format-to-a-date)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this, can easier option is `as.yearmon`

```
library(zoo)
as.Date(as.yearmon(x$Date, "%m-%y"))
```

---

Or paste with a day and then `format`

```
as.Date(paste0(x$Date, "-01"), "%m-%y-%d")
```