# converting `"7-2014"`into date format and finding minimum in R

Tags: r, date, as.date

I have date stored as `character` in  the vector `date`

```
> head(date)
[1] "7-2014"  "1-2018"  "11-2014" "7-2014"  "1-2018"  "1-2018"
```

and want to convert it to date and find its minimum.  I used `as.Date` as explained [here](https://statistics.berkeley.edu/computing/r-dates-times)

```
as.Date(date, "%m-%Y")
```

but only get `NA` as result. Why is this not working?

I want to find the minimum date in the column. If you know of a better approach, enlighten me :)

Comment: I always use lubridate for working with dates. dmy(paste0("1-", date)) would do it.

Comment: Your example might not work because as.Date() requires a day of the month as well.

Comment: For now, you could paste a leading zero and convert it

Comment: See: [Converting year and month (“yyyy-mm” format) to a date](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6242955/10488504)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as.Date requires a day of the month:

```
date <- c("7-2014",  "1-2018",  "11-2014", "7-2014",  "1-2018",  "1-2018")
as.Date(paste0("1-", date), "%d-%m-%Y")
#> [1] "2014-07-01" "2018-01-01" "2014-11-01" "2014-07-01" "2018-01-01"
#> [6] "2018-01-01"
```

<sup>Created on 2020-04-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You can put an arbitrary date in the vector and convert it into date to calculate `min`.

Or you can also use `zoo`s `yearmon`

```
min(zoo::as.yearmon(x, "%m-%Y"))
#[1] "Jul 2014"
```

**data**

```
x <- c("7-2014" , "1-2018",  "11-2014", "7-2014",  "1-2018",  "1-2018")
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also use `lubridate` after appending a day at the end

```
library(lubridate)
min(myd(paste0(x, '-1')))
```

#### data

```
x <- c("7-2014" , "1-2018",  "11-2014", "7-2014",  "1-2018",  "1-2018")
```