# Convert a column having Abbreviated Month-Year format to Date Type

Tags: r

I have a column with strings of the form - "Nov - 16", "Apr - 18" and I would like R to recognize this as date columns.
I've tried using as.Date and Zoom. The former gave me a bunch of NAs and the latter threw an error.

Comment: You'll need to add a day (e.g. "01 - ") with `paste`, then can use the lubridate function `dmy()`. As far as I know you need to include some kind of day indicator to convert to a date object.

Comment: `as.Date(paste("01", c("Nov - 16", "Apr - 18")), format = "%d %b - %y")` worked for me.

Comment: Or you can convert to `zoo`'s `yearmon` class. `zoo::as.yearmon(x, '%b - %y')` You need to change the format here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242955/converting-year-and-month-yyyy-mm-format-to-a-date

Comment: I do not see how this question can be downvoted. It may seem like a basic question to some, but even beginners use Stackoverflow.

Comment: desert_ranger, don't sweat one-off downvotes: sometimes people just want to downvote. If I had to guess, it's because you don't include actual code attempted or literal variable declarations, though in this case it was good enough to contrive sample data. Either way, the anonymous nature of votes on Stack sites (something I wholeheartedly support) makes it easy for un- or under-justified downvotes, where ideally they would be accompanied by rationale (that can be addressed/fixed or at least understood). \*shrug\*

Comment: @r2evans Thank you for the encouragement and information!

Comment: And the vote to close as a duplicate is also justified, as this is a common question (with many answers on SO). For me it was quicker at the moment to just compile the comments into an answer, perhaps ideally I should have spent another 3 minutes to find the right dupe and close it without the answer. "Dupe" closure is not intended as a negative, just trying to keep the most prominent/complete/appropriate answer relevant instead of hundreds of nearly-identical questions/answers on the same issue. (The only thing it reflects on you is that you didn't find it on previous SO searching.)

Comment: I agree with this point too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sum up the comments so far:

```r
vec <- c("Nov - 16", "Apr - 18")
(o1 <- as.Date(paste("01", vec), format = "%d %b - %y"))
# [1] "2016-11-01" "2018-04-01"
(o2 <- lubridate::dmy(paste("01", vec)))
# [1] "2016-11-01" "2018-04-01"
(o3 <- zoo::as.yearmon(vec, "%b - %y"))
# [1] "Nov 2016" "Apr 2018"
```

It should be noted that the first two produce objects of class `Date`, and the third returns class `yearmon`, and their relative numeric values are a bit different:

```r
dput(o1)
# structure(c(17106, 17622), class = "Date")
dput(o2)
# structure(c(17106, 17622), class = "Date")
dput(o3)
# structure(c(2016.83333333333, 2018.25), class = "yearmon")
```

though you can always convert from the third if need be, as suggested by @RonakShah.

```r
as.Date(o3)
# [1] "2016-11-01" "2018-04-01"
```