# How to convert character column to date?

Tags: r, datetime, format, as.date, yearmonth

My data frame:

```
  yearmonth basinflow
  <chr>         <dbl>
1 1966-01   0.000105 
2 1966-02   0.0000946
3 1966-03   0.816    
4 1966-04   5.17     
5 1966-05   0.102    
6 1966-06   0.0729
```

I want to add a column with just the month values, but converting the yearmonth to a date with as.Date is not working.

```
as.Date(df_Month$yearmonth, format = "%Y-%m")

[1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
 [35] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

And result is this. What can I try? Or is there a way to only call the month portion without it being a date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need a day as well for `Date` class which we can `paste` and then either use `%Y-%m-%d` or skip the `format` as the default format is `%Y-%m-%d`

```
as.Date(paste0(df_Month$yearmonth, "-01"), format = "%Y-%m-%d")
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to convert to date first? You can just extract the month form the string. This will extract everything after the '-' from the string as a numeric type.

`as.numeric(gsub(".*-","",df_Month$yearmonth))`

Answer (score 0):

This question was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242955/converting-year-and-month-yyyy-mm-format-to-a-date) using the `zoo::as.yearmon()` function and/or the above solution.