# Convert a date with only years and months to datetime in R

Tags: r, datetime

The date columns in my df have only year and month as a string (eg `"2009-09"`), and therefore conversion to datetime using `as.POSIXct` doesn't seem to work.

I considered the following solution to fix this:

```
df$col <- past0(df$col, '-01')
df$col <- as.POSITXct(df$col, format='%Y-%m-%d', tz='UCT')
```

Which seems to work. My questions are:

1. Is this indeed an acceptable solution or may I encounter problems further down the line?
2. Is there a way of dealing with this directly with `as.POSITXct` that would make redundant the line that pastes the day?

EDIT for any future readers: My question is answered here [Converting year and month ("yyyy-mm" format) to a date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242955/converting-year-and-month-yyyy-mm-format-to-a-date)

I couldn't find it during my initial searches.

Comment: Looks good, maybe "-01".

Comment: @user2974951 that's actually what I did in my original script - typing error when writing the question. Thanks for picking it up!

Answer (score 2):

It is an underspecified problem.  A *date* needs year, month and day.  Now, some helper functions add the date (by convention the first) to help you. `anydate()` is one:

```
> vector1 <- c("2009-08", "2009-10", "2010-08")
> vector2 <- c("2009-08", "2009-07", "2009-09")
> anytime::anydate(c(vector1, vector2))
[1] "2009-08-01" "2009-10-01" "2010-08-01" "2009-08-01" "2009-07-01" "2009-09-01"
>
```

The returned object is of the desired type:

```
> class(anytime::anydate(c(vector1, vector2)))
[1] "Date"
>
```